# BizTalk 2016 Missing Sql Management Tools

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm configuring a new BizTalk 2016 install, Sql 2016 is installed on a separate server. I get the usual error re missing integration services.

[image]

So, at this point I go to Sandro's blog post to remind me what I missed: [Sandro's Post](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2011/08/31/biztalk-2010-bam-tools-configuration-error-microsoft-sql-server-data-transformation-services-dts-2008-with-sp1-or-higher-for-bam-archiving-is-not-installed-on-the-local-machine/)

Problem is, the resolution no longer applies because the option for "Management Tools - Basic" / "Management Tools - Complete" is no longer an option, from the Sql Server 2016 Setup Wizard:

[image: Options Missing]

So, I go back to the 1st page of the Wizard and Notice the Option for "Install SQL Server Management Tools":

[image: Page1]

Trouble is, clicking this just attempts to navigate to a page on the web, to download SSMS v17.4. There is no internet connectivity out from this BizTalk server. So, I download from a laptop then get SSMS v17.4 installed onto the BizTalk server. I then restart the BizTalk configuration application (import my previously saved config and re-enter all the passwords!), this does not help with SSIS problem.

Does anyone know what I can install on the BizTalk application server to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was, BizTalk config not happy with the version of SSMS had been installed. Solution was to remove v17.4 then download v16.5.3 from the following and install it: [Microsoft Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms#previous-ssms-releases)